# This works, but is it the "right" way?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-inflate

I'm reusing the ListView AND the LayoutInflater here for both a header and a footer:

```
ListView lv = getListView(); 
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
View header = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false);
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

View footer = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, lv, false);
lv.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
```

I reckon reusing the ListView is perfectly sensible, but I'm not so sure about the LayoutInflater. Am I flirting with disaster here, or is this okay?

Comment: to call getLayoutInflater(); once is fine :) the rest is also fine if you look at other samples they do it allover with inflater.inflate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getFooterViewsCount()

> Returns the number of footer views in the list. Footer views are
>   special views at the bottom of the list that should not be recycled
>   during a layout.

So yeah... I don't think you are doing anything wrong.